# Custom Gradle plugin doLast() in task

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am writing a custom Gradle plugin and trying to figure out how can I call a `doLast()` function inside my Gradle plugin then supplying some logic in there, but unfortunately with not much success.

This is syntax error at `it.delete(` `Unresolved reference: delete`:

```
project.tasks.create("cleanMendix", Delete::class.java) {task ->
    task.doLast{
        it.delete(
            "${project.projectDir}/target",
            "${project.projectDir}/.mendix-cache",
            "${project.projectDir}/userlib",
            "${project.projectDir}/deployment"
        )
    }
}.apply {
    group = "mendix"
}
```

This is not deleting the files:

```
        project.tasks.create("cleanMendix", Delete::class.java) {task ->
        task.doLast{
            task.delete(
                "${project.projectDir}/target",
                "${project.projectDir}/.mendix-cache",
                "${project.projectDir}/userlib",
                "${project.projectDir}/deployment"
            )
        }
    }.apply {
        group = "mendix"
    }
```

If I call without `doLast()` it's working but it is also run in the configuration phase.

Comment: Is there a task that is creating the items you are deleting?